# Retrieving Project Metrics using Rest API and Timemachine from SonarQube

Tags: rest, sonarqube, metrics

I'm trying to retrieve projects metrics using the REST Api. Therefore I first query the projects using *"/api/projects/index"*. Afterwards I retrieve the metrics using *"/api/metrics/search"*. Both works fine. And I result with:

- [id:35476, k:com.test:TestProject, nm:TestProject, qu:TRK, sc:PRJ]
- [custom:false, description:Cyclomatic complexity, direction:-1, domain:Complexity, hidden:false, id:10019, key:complexity, name:Complexity, qualitative:false, type:INT]

Now I wanted to retrieve a projects metrics. Therefore I use the following URL: 
*https://MYHOST/sonarqube/api/timemachine/index?resource=35476&metric=10019&fromDateTime=2010-12-25T23:59:59+0100&toDateTime=2018-12-25T23:59:59+0100*

There the server retruns only: [{"cols":[],"cells":[]}]

This surprices me, because when I enter the WebInterface of sonar for the project, I can see numbers. I tried some other metrics, however all ended with the same result. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention server version, so I'll assume the latest: 5.2.

I got the same result for a bare query (`http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/timemachine/index`), and for a query which specified resource but not metrics (`http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/timemachine/index?resource=org.sonarsource.sonarqube%3Asonarqube`).

So I'm guessing there's a problem with either your resource or metric id. Try using the keys (com.test&%3ATestProject, and complexity) instead.

And yes, the ids you got back from the other web services *should* work here, but what's meant by "id" can be a little... ah... variable from service to service to service.

Comment: Found it in my case. The problem was neither the URL call nor the IDs. It was a parameter: metric!=metrics. Thanks for the help. I'm using 5.2